# Python: troubleshooting scikit-image module installation

Tags: python, module, scipy, importerror, scikit-image

I've been using python for a while but want to extend it's capabilities. I've installed SciPy and it's related packages via [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads), created the py3k environment as per [these instructions](http://continuum.io/blog/anaconda-python-3), and every module I tested seems to work fine - except for one I particularly want to use.

When I try to run the Getting Started example on the [frontpage of scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) I end up with [this error](http://pastebin.com/uGAwS1j5). I tried installing scikit-image (and it's dependencies) separately, when I did the script ran without errors but no image appeared.

```
from skimage import data, io, filter

image = data.coins() # or any NumPy array!
edges = filter.sobel(image)
io.imshow(edges)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also call `io.show` to bring up the display window. Otherwise, use matplotlib to visualise the image. Please see the examples gallery on http://scikit-image.org.